# Reading image data (R,G, & B pixel) into 2D arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, image, multidimensional-array

I'm able to read the header file of an image fine, but I'm having trouble putting the first data value for the red channel,for example, 206, into a 2D array `ppmImage.red[0][0]`. A white space follows and then the first value for the green channel, and so on.

Below is what I am currently doing and instead of 206 being in `ppmImage.red[0][0]`, I have `ppmImage.red[0][0]`= 2, `ppmImage.green[0][0]`=0, and `ppmImage.blue[0][0]`=6. For reference, these will only be 8 bit values and thus red, green, and blue are of type pixel and are `unsigned char`.

```
void readTextData(fstream &fin, struct ppmImage &image)
{
int iii, jjj;

for(iii = 0; iii < image.rows ; iii++)
{
    for(jjj = 0; jjj < image.cols; jjj++)
    {
        fin >> image.red[iii][jjj];     
        fin >> image.green[iii][jjj];
        fin >>image.blue[iii][jjj]; 
    }
}

fin.close();
}
```

I thought `fin >>` would read until it hit white space but I was mistaken. I also tried using `fin.read((char *) & image.redgray[iii][jjj],sizeof(pixel));` but ended up with the same results.

The data could be in a form like:

```
1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8 9
```

and I'm not sure how I would deal with the '\n'.

I've searched for information and end up more confused than I already am. I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction or someone pointing out my stupidity. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a simple fix, you have to read integers not unsigned char. Since your image uses unsigned char all you need to do add is some temporary ints for the read.

```
    int red, green, blue;
    fin >> red >> green >> blue; 
    image.red[iii][jjj] = red;
    image.green[iii][jjj] = green;
    image.blue[iii][jjj] = blue;
```

I am assuming that your image file is a text file, that seems to be the case from your description.

Comment: Yes it is a text file, I should have been more clear. And wow, I swear I tried something like that earlier! Thank you so much for the quick and succinct answer. I tried up-voting for you but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, I'd change from a structure containing arrays, to an array of structures:

```
struct pixel { 
    unsigned char red, green, blue;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, pixel &p) { 
        unsigned int red, green, blue;
        is >> red >> green >> blue;
        p.red = red;
        p.green = green;
        p.blue = blue;
        return is;
    }
};

// ...

for (i = 0; i<image.cols; i++)
    for (j=0; j<image.rows; j++)
        if (!infile >> pixels[i][j])
            break; // read failed
```

Comment: I picked the answer above because it was a quick-fix to my problem, but thank you. Out of curiosity, what advantage does an array of structures have over a structure containing arrays?

Comment: @user2856909: It depends somewhat on what you're doing with the data, but (for example) if you decide to copy some pixels around, it lets you copy an entire pixels as `pixels[x1][y1] = pixels[x2[y2];` instead of `red[x1][y1] = red[x2][y2]; green[x1][y1] = green[x2][y2]; blue[x1][y1]=blue[x2][y2];`